# Can't JOIN on table if it is selected twice

Tags: mysql, join, select, multiple-tables

I'm trying to build a query in MySQL which looks like this:

```
select
  t1.id
  ,t1Next.code as nextCode
  ,t1Prev.code as prevCode
from
  t1
  ,(select * from t2 where idMain in (idList)) as t2Main
  ,(select * from t2 where idAssoc in (idList)) as t2Assoc
inner join t1 as t1Next on t1Next.id = t2Main.idAssoc
inner join t1 as t1Prev on t1Prev.id = t2Assoc.idMain
where t1.id in (idList)
  and t2Main.idMain = t1.id
  and t2Assoc.idAssoc = t1.id
```

Which is coming back with the error `Unknown column 't2Main.idAssoc' in 'on clause'`.

This query *works*:

```
select
  t1.id
  ,t1Next.code as nextCode
from
  t1
  ,(select * from t2 where idMain in (idList)) as t2Main
inner join t1 as t1Next on t1Next.id = t2Main.idAssoc
where t1.id in (idList)
  and t2Main.idMain = t1.id
```

Adding the second subquery like this, breaks the query and results in the above error:

```
select
  t1.id
  ,t1Next.code as nextCode
from
  t1
  ,(select * from t2 where idMain in (idList)) as t2Main
  ,(select * from t2 where idAssoc in (idList)) as t2Assoc
inner join t1 as t1Next on t1Next.id = t2Main.idAssoc
where t1.id in (idList)
  and t2Main.idMain = t1.id
```

Why might this be?

Comment: It is not good to mix implicit "comma" join notation and explicit JOIN join notation...it's generally best to avoid comma join notation altogether.

Comment: Instead: `INNER JOIN (select * from t2 where idMain in (idList)) as t2Main ON t2Main.idMain = t1.id` and so on... (but I also don't see what exactly is wrong with your query to cause this besides perhaps the parser strangling itself with the implicit and explicit joins).

Comment: @JNevill My guess is that the mix is evaluated as `(t1, t2Main, (t2Assoc IJ t1Next))`, making the t2Main out of scope for explicit join. Whereas the intended logic was `(t1, t2Main, t2Assoc) IJ t1Next`